# Group by Not column X

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to

```
a = data.frame(A = 1:4,B= 2:5,c=3:6) %>% groupby(*??????*)
```

Is there an easy command togroup by columns not c? allowing me to not write out group_by(A,B) for situations where I have many columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setdiff`

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(A = 1:4,B= 2:5,c=3:6)  %>%
       group_by(across(all_of(setdiff(names(.), 'c'))))
```

Or with `-`

```
data.frame(A = 1:4,B= 2:5,c=3:6)  %>%
       group_by(across(-c))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   A, B [4]
#      A     B     c
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     3
#2     2     3     4
#3     3     4     5
#4     4     5     6
```